# How to work with UIO drivers with my network card

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming, linux-device-driver, mmap

I am trying to learn User mode driver to receive interrupts of my Network Card.

I insmod two kernel components `${KSRC}/drivers/uio/uio.ko and ${KSRC}/drivers/uio/uio_pci_generic.ko.`

But I donot see any device getting created which I can then `mmap`

Typically for UIO I would need something like `"/dev/uio0"` which I can open then `mmap()`

So how to go about using UIO framework?

**Edit:**
My network card is Marvell ethernet controller. My hardware is x86 Ubuntu. Linux kernel 3.13.11.11. So no device tree based.

Comment: What hardware are you using? With e.g. ARM devices you need to add a node to your device tree to represent the hardware.

Comment: x86, no device tree based.

Comment: Maybe executing mknod explicitly is required, as is done on this page http://dpdk.org/ml/archives/dev/2014-October/006373.html

Comment: Please answer this question yourself, if you were able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the driver has to be compiled into the kernel. Either use menu config or add the following lines to a *.cfg* file.  You can check that the driver has been compiled by looking in `/lib/modules/<kernel-name>/modules.builtin`.

```
CONFIG_UIO=y
CONFIG_UIO_PDRV_GENIRQ=y
```

The next step is to add the following entry to your device tree  You can check that the driver has been compiled by looking in `/lib/modules/<kernel-name>/modules.builtin`.file. Where the middle number is the interrupt you are targeting -32. This means 0x1D == 29 and then add 32 for the interrupt number that is registered in the GIC (Generic Interrupt Controller on ARM systems).

```
spw0@7aa00000 {
  compatible = "generic-uio";
  reg = <0x7aa00000 0x10000>;
  interrupts = <0x0 0x1D 0x4>;
  interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
  clocks = <0x1>;
};
```

and changing the bootargs to `console=ttyPS0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rw rootwait earlyprintk uio_pdrv_genirq.of_id=generic-uio`.

If everything goes well, you will see the `/dev/uio0` device after booting up.